# a html form that spans across a page

Tags: html, forms

I'm making a messaging platform that has a checkbox input on every message received. I want to have the functionality that a user can click a checkbox and than a button at the top of the page to delete the message. how can I format a html form to complete this?

`-header html-`

`<form action='/action.php'>`

`-the top section of the page-`

`<input type='checkbox'>`

basically, I want the input to post to the form at the top, what would be the most effective way of doing this? preferably without JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `form` atrribute to assign checkboxes to the desired form ID:

```
<form action='/action.php'id="theform"></form>

-the top section of the page-

<input type='checkbox' form='theform'>
```